# How to resolve ip_options_compile, EXPORT_SYMBOL

Tags: linux, netfilter

I want to use the function defined in in `net/ip_options.c` file like `ip_options_compile`, `ip_options_build` in my netfilter module.

I want to put options into IP packets. I have inserted the header file that declares these function. I have used `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, but I get warning, `"ip_options_compile" undefined`.

Any suggestions will be greatly respected.

Comment: Your description is a bit too vague. When exactly do you get undefined, and what is the *exact* wording? NB: `ip_options_compile` is already exported since 2.6.37.

Answer (score 0):

Why not including the file `#include <net/ip.h>` ? The prototypes are all defined and externed.